# Result of the callback function being executed with the two numbers

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Need a bit of help solving this! Thanks in advance!

Write a function named callbackFunc that takes in two numbers and a callback function, and returns the result of the callback function being executed with the two numbers.

```
//DON'T CHANGE THIS CODE
function adder(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

function subtractor(x, y) {
    return x - y;
}

function multiplier(x, y) {
    return x * y;
}

//Code here
function callbackFunc(num1, num2, callback) {

}


//DON'T CHANGE THIS EITHER pls
var x = callbackFunc(2, 3, adder); // x = 5
var y = callbackFunc(5, 2, subtractor); // y = 3
var z = callbackFunc(3, 6, multiplier); // z = 18
```

Comment: Have you tried anything inside of `callbackFunc` so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just invoke the callback in the function

```
function callbackFunc(num1, num2, callback) {
return  callback(num1,num2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I typed that previously but it didn't work... Maybe had a typo

Comment: np .. please approve the answer if you can :)